# Adding Spring project to Spring Boot project as a dependency in the pom.xml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a Spring Project and I want to add it (as dependency) to a Spring boot project. Is it possible?

I don't really know if I say something of really impossible (I don't know spring boot).

Comment: whats worry, you can do it, add the project dependency in pom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.

1. Change `<packaging>` from `war` to `jar` in pom.xml of the spring project.

   `<packaging>jar</packaging>`
2. Do a Maven clean and Maven install - Command : `mvn clean install` to produce a jar
   file of the spring project.
3. Create local repository of the jar to be held in the `.m2` folder.

Command to create it- `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<<path>><<name of the jar>>.jar -DgroupId=<<base package name>> -DartifactId=<<name of the jar>> -Dversion=<<version number>> -Dpackaging=jar`

4. Now, add the dependency in the pom.xml of the spring-boot project.

   ```
   `<dependency>
        <groupId><<base package name>></groupId>
        <artifactId><<name of the jar>></artifactId>
        <version><<version number>></version>
    </dependency>`
   ```

That's it.

**Note : Download the maven and set it to the path variable of the system.**